# Why this JavaScript code fails in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I found below JavaScript code snippet in [adsense's developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/docs/implementation-guide) site which allows me to inject external JS file into an iFrame when added few other parameters.

```
    (function(g,o){g[o]=g[o]||function(){(g[o]['q']=g[o]['q']||[]).push(
  arguments)},g[o]['t']=1*new Date})(window,'_googCsa');
```

When I tried to use above snippet in a Typescript file it gives me an error(shown in the picture down below). I tried fixing it but nothing was successful.
[image]

Please help me fix this code snippet. I would like to use that snippet in an angular app component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript has a problem with using multiplication on a date.  In this code, multiplication is being used to implicitly coerce the `Date` to a `number`.  However, you can just accomplish the same thing explicitly.

```
(new Date).valueOf()
```

Comment: It worked. Is there any documentation that I can follow to know all this?

Comment: There is a lot of documentation about a lot of things in a lot of places.  Here's some documentation for `.valueOf()`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf